# comparing tuples in python

Tags: python, comparison, tuples, pacman

I have the following piece of code:

```
while current is not problem.getStartState():

        print "Current: ", current, "Start: ", problem.getStartState()
```

now for some reason the comparison is not working well, you can see in the following output:

```
Current:  (3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0) Start:  (4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Current:  (4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0) Start:  (4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

you can see that even though current is the same as getStartState() it enters the while. furthermore - when it used to be a 2 fields tuple (x,y) it worked fine.

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: can you post `getSTartSTate()` code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` tests for identity, not equality. You want `current != problem.getStartState()`

There is an idiom `is (not) None` which works because `None` is guaranteed to be a singleton. Don't use it for other types unless you really mean it!

Comment: Thanks, understood my problem, but i did not understand - how come it worked on a 2 fields tuple as I mentioned ?

Comment: @antisane: Unfortunately for learners (but fortunately for memory consumption), the interpreter takes a few shortcuts and sometimes reuses immutable objects when possible. Small integers have the same "problem". Don't rely on it.

Comment: @antisane: moreover, different python interpreters behave differently. For example, "(2,3) is (2,3)" returns False on my python 2.7.1, but True on my pypy 1.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
while current != problem.getStartState():

    print "Current: ", current, "Start: ", problem.getStartState()
```

`is` is the identity (same objects) comparator. In your case, you need an equality (or inequality) (objects with same values) operator.

Answer (score -1):

**is** is not the correct check to be used in this case.
To compare 2 tuples just use != or ==

for instance the problem can be solved as follows:

```
while current != problem.getStartState():   
        print "Current: ", current, "Start: ", problem.getStartState()
```

cheers,